# RDWeb Application Causes desktop flicker

Tags: windows-server-2012, .net, remoteapp, web-applications, rdweb

I am working on testing for future migration from a Terminal Server environment a full Published Desktop set up using RD Web Access in a Server 2012.

I am currently experiencing an issue with a program that once it launches, it is causing a type of screen flicker.  Now the flicker is not automatic, in fact the flicker only occurs when you click on the actual program itself within the window it runs on. It then causes the background of your desktop to black out, and in some cases become an epileptics worst nightmare as you open other windows for the application.

All other applications run fine no problems, it is just this one program that is having an issue.  The only thing that I know of that separates this application from the other applications we have published is that it is a .Net built program.  This application runs from a TS environment with no problems and runs on all of our 2012 servers no problem.  It also runs just fine as a Published app currently from one of our 2008 R2 servers.  But from this 2012 servers RDWeb app this application has not been friendly.

My test environment includes the following: All VM servers.

1 Connection Broker Server
1 Web Access Server
2 Session Host Servers

Testing RDWeb applications from a Windows 8 Pro Client and a Windows 7 SP1 client

Both Clients experiencing the same exact flicker problem.

I have scoured for answers for several days, with trying a few different options including trying to make tweeks to Windows Desktop experience, RemoteFX, themes and other things to see if I can find a possible solution, so far I am coming up empty so I am trying to reach out to the community to see if anyone has ran across this before or would be able to help me find a possible solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so this goes in an answer.

Does your .net application use WPF? The only time I've seen screen flicker problems on RDS platforms was a bug in Server 2003 Terminal Services. QuickBooks' use of WPF caused it to randomly flicker the same way you describe. In that case it was because of a permission problem on Server 2003 that caused non-admin users to experience flicker. Microsoft issued a hotfix for that problem.

Windows Presentation Foundation might be the source of your problem. Either in the way it is implemented in the application code or in it's execution on Server 2012.